# Attaching SQLite 3 databases with PHP?

Tags: php, database, sqlite, cordova

I've been researching this question for a long time, and I always think I have the answer, but it never works. Basically, I have four .sqlite3 files that I need to perform transactions **across**. So... I researched attaching them, and thought I had it...

Anyway, I'm trying to create a database in memory, attach the other four to it, then perform operations across all four. I don't need the memory database, but it sounded like it made things a lot easier.

I've only ever done SQLite with JavaScript before, and have almost no experience with PHP.

In this example, $pathToMesh is an absolute path to a folder containing two .sqlite3 files, and $pathToUser leads to another folder with different files with the same two names. I always get the response "File Exists" and then when I try to perform basic SQLite on these databases (in the format `database.table_name`), it just dies. I've been trying to look for an error message, but because I call this PHP from Ajax within a PhoneGap application, I can't see what's going on.

```
if (file_exists($pathToMesh . $dbame) && file_exists($pathToMesh . $sbame)) {
    echo "File Exists";
    $db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
    $db->query("ATTACH DATABASE '" . $pathToMesh . $dbname . "' AS meshStats");
    $db->query("ATTACH DATABASE '" . $pathToMesh . $sbname . "' AS meshSB");
    $db->query("ATTACH DATABASE '" . $pathToUser . $dbname . "' AS upStats");
    $db->query("ATTACH DATABASE '" . $pathToUser . $sbname . "' AS upSB");
    //Code continued
else {
    echo "Files don't exist.";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention `$pathToUser` in your question but it doesn't exist in your code.

Comment: Yes it does... Check the third and fourth ATTACH statements. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  You do not check to see if those databases exist, though.

Comment: I do earlier. All this code is wrapped in an IF statement that checks the file existing just as it does with `$pathToMesh`. Hmmmm... I still can't get it.